# Light Calculation For Triangles - Raytracing

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, metal, raytracing

**Background:**
I am trying to write a "raytracer" (really a pathtracer) using metal, c++, and swiftui. I've been studying raytracing using the Raytracing in One Weekend series, Cherno's raytracing course, and PBRT plus other articles I can find on raytracing/ path tracing but I honestly still feel like I have no idea what I'm doing. It feels like there is so much knowledge to learn and even after so much studying I barely have made a dent.

**Question:**
Initially I want to write some simple code to light lambertian diffuse materials, I believe that my emission calculations for sphere's here is correct but cannot figure out the math behind emission for triangles. My scene is structured as a Cornell box and I use four triangles to create two emissive planes to light the scene. I would greatly appreciate if someone is able to help identify what am I doing wrong in this metal code below.

I believe the issue lies somewhere in my calculateLightData method/ perPixelMetal method.

I am aware that generally it is best practice to create separate light objects but I come from a background as a 3D artist where using emissive objects to light scenes can also be common. This is why I have opted to attempt creating purely emissive objects for scene lighting.

Note: Sorry I'm sure this code is probably horrible, I would more than appreciate links to the proper resources to help me solve this question on my own and set myself up for building my raytracer to be more complex in the future.

```
//
//  Compute.metal
//  BlueLeafRenderer
//
//  Created by Sahil Srivastava on 9/23/23.
//

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct Ray {
    simd_float3 origin;
    simd_float3 direction;
};

struct HitPayload {
    float hitDistance;
    simd_float3 worldPosition;
    simd_float3 worldNormal;
    uint objectIndex;
};

struct Material {
    simd_float3 albedo;
    simd_float3 emissionColor;
    float emissionPower;
};

struct Sphere {
    simd_float3 position;
    float radius;
};

struct Triangle {
    simd_float3 vertex0;
    simd_float3 vertex1;
    simd_float3 vertex2;
};

enum GeometryType {
    SPHERE = 0,
    TRIANGLE = 1
};

struct Geometry {
    union {
        Sphere sphere;
        Triangle triangle;
    };
    GeometryType type;
    uint materialIndex;
};

struct Camera {
    simd_float3 position;
};

struct RendererData {
    uint frameIndex;
    uint rendererWidth;
    uint rendererHeight;
    float4x4 inverseProjection;
    float4x4 inverseView;
};

struct BRDFResult {
    simd_float3 brdf;
    simd_float3 direction;
};


// MARK: Random

uint32_t pcg_hash(uint32_t seed) {
    uint32_t state = seed * 747796405u + 2891336453u;
    uint32_t word = ((state >> ((state >> 28u) + 4u)) ^ state) * 277803737u;
    return (word >> 22u) ^ word;
}

float randomFloat(device uint32_t* seed, uint gid) {
    seed[gid] = pcg_hash(seed[gid]);
    return (float)seed[gid] / (float)__UINT32_MAX__;
}

// MARK: Intersection+Payload

bool intersectSphere(constant Sphere& sphere, Ray ray, thread float& hitDistance) {
    const float EPSILON = 0.0000001;
    simd_float3 originToCenter = ray.origin - sphere.position;
    float a = dot(ray.direction, ray.direction);
    float b = 2.0f * dot(originToCenter, ray.direction);
    float c = dot(originToCenter, originToCenter) - sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    float discriminant = b * b - 4.0f * a * c;
    if (discriminant < 0.0f) {
        return false; // No real roots, ray does not intersect
    }
    float sqrtDiscriminant = sqrt(discriminant);
    float t1 = (-b - sqrtDiscriminant) / (2.0f * a);
    float t2 = (-b + sqrtDiscriminant) / (2.0f * a);
    // Select the appropriate intersection point
    if (t1 > EPSILON && t1 < hitDistance) {
        hitDistance = t1;
        return true;
    } else if (t2 > EPSILON && t2 < hitDistance) {
        hitDistance = t2;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool intersectTriangle(constant Triangle& triangle, Ray ray, thread float& hitDistance) {
    const float EPSILON = 0.0000001;
    simd_float3 vertex0 = triangle.vertex0;
    simd_float3 vertex1 = triangle.vertex1;
    simd_float3 vertex2 = triangle.vertex2;
    simd_float3 edge1 = vertex1 - vertex0;
    simd_float3 edge2 = vertex2 - vertex0;
    simd_float3 h = cross(ray.direction, edge2);
    float a = dot(edge1, h);
    if (a > -EPSILON && a < EPSILON)
        return false; // Ray is parallel to the triangle.
    float f = 1.0 / a;
    simd_float3 s = ray.origin - vertex0;
    float u = f * dot(s, h);
    if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        return false;
    simd_float3 q = cross(s, edge1);
    float v = f * dot(ray.direction, q);
    if (v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0)
        return false;
    float t = f * dot(edge2, q);
    if (t > EPSILON && t < hitDistance) {
        hitDistance = t;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void payloadSphere(Ray ray, thread HitPayload& payload, constant Sphere& sphere, float hitDistance) {
    // work in sphere's local coord system to simplify hit calc
    simd_float3 origin = ray.origin - sphere.position;
    payload.worldPosition = origin + ray.direction * hitDistance;
    simd_float3 normal = normalize(payload.worldPosition);
    // Flip normal if ray originates inside the sphere
    if (dot(ray.direction, normal) > 0.0f) {
        normal = -normal;
    }
    payload.worldNormal = normal;
    payload.worldPosition += sphere.position; // translate back to world coords
}

void payloadTriangle(Ray ray, thread HitPayload& payload, constant Triangle& triangle, float hitDistance) {
    simd_float3 edge1 = triangle.vertex1 - triangle.vertex0;
    simd_float3 edge2 = triangle.vertex2 - triangle.vertex0;
    simd_float3 normal = normalize(cross(edge1, edge2));
    // Check if the ray is inside the geometry and flip the normal
    if (dot(ray.direction, normal) > 0.0f) {
        normal = -normal;
    }
    payload.worldPosition = ray.origin + ray.direction * hitDistance;
    payload.worldNormal = normal;
}

// MARK: Light

simd_float3 randomInHemisphere(device uint32_t* seed, uint gid, simd_float3 normal) {
    float u = randomFloat(seed, gid);
    float v = randomFloat(seed, gid);
    
    float r = sqrt(u);
    float theta = 2.0f * M_PI_F * v;
    
    // Generate a random point on unit disk
    simd_float3 onDisk = simd_float3(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta), 0.0f);
    
    // Create an orthogonal coordinate system using the normal
    simd_float3 w = normal;
    simd_float3 a = (fabs(w.x) > 0.1f ? simd_float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) : simd_float3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    simd_float3 uCoord = normalize(cross(a, w));
    simd_float3 vCoord = cross(w, uCoord);
    
    // Convert point on disk to a point on hemisphere
    return normalize(onDisk.x * uCoord + onDisk.y * vCoord + sqrt(1.0f - u) * w);
}

simd_float3 cosineWeightedInHemisphere(device uint32_t* seed, uint gid, simd_float3 normal) {
    float r1 = randomFloat(seed, gid);
    float r2 = randomFloat(seed, gid);
    
    // Polar coordinates
    float phi = 2.0f * M_PI_F * r1;
    float x = cos(phi) * sqrt(r2);
    float y = sin(phi) * sqrt(r2);
    float z = sqrt(1.0f - r2);
    
    // Construct an orthonormal basis with 'normal' as one of the axes
    simd_float3 w = normal;
    simd_float3 a = (fabs(w.x) > 0.9f) ? simd_float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) : simd_float3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    simd_float3 v = normalize(cross(a, w));
    simd_float3 u = cross(w, v);
    
    // Transform the sampled direction to align with the normal
    simd_float3 direction = normalize(x * u + y * v + z * w);
    
    return direction;
}

BRDFResult lambertianBRDF(device uint32_t* seed, uint gid, constant Material& material, simd_float3 normal) {
    simd_float3 newDirection = cosineWeightedInHemisphere(seed, gid, normal);
    simd_float3 brdf = material.albedo / M_PI_F;
    return {brdf, newDirection};
}

struct LightData {
    simd_float3 direction;
    simd_float3 intensity;
    float dist;
};

LightData calculateLightData(simd_float3 hitPoint, constant Geometry& object, constant Material& material) {
    LightData lightData;
    lightData.direction = simd_float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    lightData.intensity = simd_float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float lightDist = 0.0f;
    
    if (material.emissionPower > 0.0f) {
        if (object.type == SPHERE) {
            simd_float3 lightDir = hitPoint - object.sphere.position;
            float r2 = dot(lightDir, lightDir);
            lightDist = sqrt(r2);
            lightDir /= lightDist;
            lightData.intensity = material.emissionColor * material.emissionPower / (4 * M_PI_F * r2);
            lightData.direction = lightDir;
            lightData.dist = lightDist;
        } else if (object.type == TRIANGLE) {
            simd_float3 v0 = object.triangle.vertex0;
            simd_float3 v1 = object.triangle.vertex1;
            simd_float3 v2 = object.triangle.vertex2;
            simd_float3 lightDir = hitPoint - (v0 + v1 + v2) / 3.0f;
            float lightDist = length(lightDir);
            lightDir /= lightDist;
            simd_float3 edge1 = v1 - v0;
            simd_float3 edge2 = v2 - v0;
            simd_float3 tNormal = normalize(cross(edge1, edge2));
            float cosAngle = dot(lightDir, tNormal);
            if (cosAngle < 0) cosAngle = 0;
            float solidAngle = 2 * M_PI_F * (1 - cosAngle);
            lightData.intensity = material.emissionColor *
                                  material.emissionPower * cosAngle /
                                  (lightDist * lightDist * solidAngle);
            lightData.direction = lightDir;
            lightData.dist = lightDist;
        }
    }
    return lightData;
}

bool isInShadow(simd_float3 hitPoint, constant Geometry* objects, constant uint* numObjects, constant Material* materials, simd_float3 lightDirection, uint lightIndex, float distanceToLight) {
    Ray shadowRay;
    shadowRay.origin = hitPoint;
    shadowRay.direction = -lightDirection;
    for (uint i = 0; i < *numObjects; i++) {
        if (i == lightIndex) return false; // Skip the light source itself
        float hitDistance = distanceToLight;
        if (objects[i].type == SPHERE && intersectSphere(objects[i].sphere, shadowRay, hitDistance)) {
            if (materials[objects[i].materialIndex].emissionPower <= 0.0f) {
                return true; // Hit a non-emissive object - point is in shadow
            }
        } else if (objects[i].type == TRIANGLE && intersectTriangle(objects[i].triangle, shadowRay, hitDistance)) {
            if (materials[objects[i].materialIndex].emissionPower <= 0.0f) {
                return true; // Hit a non-emissive object - point is in shadow
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // No obstruction to the light source
}

// MARK: Core Raytracing

simd_float3 rayDirection(constant RendererData* rendererData, uint gid) {
    uint32_t x = gid % rendererData->rendererWidth;
    uint32_t y = gid / rendererData->rendererWidth;
    
    simd_float2 coord = { (float)x / (float)rendererData->rendererWidth, (float)y / (float)rendererData->rendererHeight };
    coord = coord * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    
    float4 target = rendererData->inverseProjection * float4(coord.x, coord.y, 1, 1);
    return (rendererData->inverseView * float4(normalize(float3(target.x, target.y, target.z)) / target.w, 0)).xyz;
}

HitPayload missMetal(Ray ray) {
    HitPayload payload;
    payload.hitDistance = -1.0f;
    return payload;
}

HitPayload closestHitMetal(Ray ray, float hitDistance, int objectIndex, constant Geometry* objects) {
    HitPayload payload;
    payload.hitDistance = hitDistance;
    payload.objectIndex = objectIndex;
    if (objects[objectIndex].type == SPHERE) {
        payloadSphere(ray, payload, objects[objectIndex].sphere, hitDistance);
    } else if (objects[objectIndex].type == TRIANGLE) {
        payloadTriangle(ray, payload, objects[objectIndex].triangle, hitDistance);
    } else {
        return missMetal(ray);
    }
    return payload;
}

HitPayload traceRayMetal(Ray ray, constant Geometry* objects, constant uint* numObjects) {
    int closestObjectIndex = -1;
    float hitDistance = FLT_MAX;
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < *numObjects; i++) {
        if (objects[i].type == SPHERE && intersectSphere(objects[i].sphere, ray, hitDistance)) {
            closestObjectIndex = i;
        } else if (objects[i].type == TRIANGLE && intersectTriangle(objects[i].triangle, ray, hitDistance)) {
            closestObjectIndex = i;
        }
    }
    
    if (closestObjectIndex < 0)
        return missMetal(ray);
    return closestHitMetal(ray, hitDistance, closestObjectIndex, objects);
}

simd_float4 perPixelMetal(constant Geometry* objects, constant uint* numObjects, constant Material* materials, constant Camera* camera, constant RendererData* rendererData, device uint32_t* seed, uint x, uint y, uint gid) {
    Ray ray;
    ray.origin = camera->position;
    ray.direction = rayDirection(rendererData, gid);
    
    simd_float3 light = simd_float3(0.0f);
    simd_float3 contribution = simd_float3(1.0f);
    
    seed[gid] = x + y * rendererData->rendererWidth;
    seed[gid] *= rendererData->frameIndex;
    
    int bounces = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < bounces; i++) {
        seed[gid] += i;
        
        HitPayload payload = traceRayMetal(ray, objects, numObjects);
        if (payload.hitDistance < 0.0f) {
            break;
        }
        // Preemptively calculate new ray
        if (i == 0 && materials[objects[payload.objectIndex].materialIndex].emissionPower > 0.0f) {
            light += contribution * materials[objects[payload.objectIndex].materialIndex].emissionPower * materials[objects[payload.objectIndex].materialIndex].emissionColor;
        } else {
            // Light calculation
            for (uint j = 0; j < *numObjects; j++) {
                if (materials[objects[j].materialIndex].emissionPower > 0.0f) {
                    LightData lightData = calculateLightData(payload.worldPosition + payload.worldNormal * 0.0001f, objects[j], materials[objects[j].materialIndex]);
                    if (!isInShadow(payload.worldPosition + payload.worldNormal * 0.0001f, objects, numObjects, materials, lightData.direction, j, lightData.dist)) {
                        light += contribution * lightData.intensity * max(0.0f, dot(payload.worldNormal, lightData.direction));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Create our new ray
        ray.origin = payload.worldPosition + payload.worldNormal * 0.0001f;
        ray.direction = cosineWeightedInHemisphere(seed, gid, payload.worldNormal); // Direction is dependent on the BRDF we use
        // Add the brdf to our light contribution
        contribution *= materials[objects[payload.objectIndex].materialIndex].albedo;
    }
    return simd_float4(light, 1.0f);
}

kernel void renderMetal(device uint32_t* buffer [[buffer(0)]],
                        constant Geometry* objects [[buffer(1)]],
                        constant uint* numObjects [[buffer(2)]],
                        constant Material* materials [[buffer(3)]],
                        constant Camera* camera [[buffer(4)]],
                        device simd_float4* accumulation [[buffer(5)]],
                        constant RendererData* rendererData [[buffer(6)]],
                        device uint32_t* seed [[buffer(7)]],
                        uint gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    uint x = gid % rendererData->rendererWidth;
    uint y = gid / rendererData->rendererWidth;
    simd_float4 color = perPixelMetal(objects, numObjects, materials, camera, rendererData, seed, x, y, gid);
    
    uint rotatedY = rendererData->rendererHeight - y - 1;
    uint index = x + rotatedY * rendererData->rendererWidth;
    
    accumulation[index] += color;
    simd_float4 accumulatedColor = accumulation[index] / (float)rendererData->frameIndex;
    
    accumulatedColor = clamp(accumulatedColor, simd_float4(0.0f), simd_float4(1.0f));
    
    const float gamma = 2.2f;
    accumulatedColor.rgb = pow(accumulatedColor.rgb, simd_float3(1.0f / gamma));
    
    uint8_t r = uint8_t(accumulatedColor.r * 255.0f);
    uint8_t g = uint8_t(accumulatedColor.g * 255.0f);
    uint8_t b = uint8_t(accumulatedColor.b * 255.0f);
    uint8_t a = uint8_t(accumulatedColor.a * 255.0f);
    
    uint32_t rgba = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
    buffer[index] = rgba;
}
```